# Инициализация в духе массива

Tags: c#

Пишу `array-like` класс, так что хотелось бы, чтобы процесс инициализации экземпляра моего класса был максимально приближен к привычной инициализации массивов

Право есть такая загвоздка:
Мы можем установить значения массива сразу, в фигурных скобках:

```
int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Чтобы реализовать подобное поведение в пользовательском классе, необходимо реализовать метод `Add`, тогда такой код:

```
MyClass my = new MyClass() { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Будет на деле развернут в

```
MyClass my = new MyClass();
my.Add(1);
my.Add(2);
my.Add(3);
```

Но, как я уже сказал, для этого потребуется делать **публичный** метод `Add`, чего хотелось бы избежать, так как он не соотносится с логикой класса

---

Пока что вижу один вариант решения проблемы:

Создать метод `Add`, но добавить к нему атрибут [BrowsableAttribute(false)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN), чтобы простые пользователи по крайней мере не видели его в списке доступных

Однако, возможно, есть более элегантное решение, о наличии которого я бы и хотел спросить у вас

Comment: а почему он не соотносится с логикой класса? Если коллекцию нельзя менять, возможно лучше передавать нужные значения в конструктор? метод Add можно сделать методом расширения

Comment: @Grundy, да коллекцию менять нельзя. А метод расширения также обладает проблемой ненужной видимости для пользователей)

Comment: Тогда никак :-) хотя можно попробовать что-то с roslyn сделать

Comment: Я бы просто через `params` в конструкторе сделал, у инициализатора перед этим способом никаких преимуществ нет

Comment: @АндрейNOP, тут я согласен. Просто такой вот косметический момент) Ничего более

Answer (score 1, accepted):

От BrowsableAttribute мало толку, он вообще похоже не имеет никакого эффекта. Используйте хотя бы [EditorBrowsableAttribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute?view=netframework-4.7), который убирает метод из IntelliSence, если класс расположен в другой сборке. Ну а лучше, если вам нужен компактный синтаксис создания класса на основе массива, просто переопределить оператор преобразования:

```
public class MyClass
{
    List<int> values = new List<int>();

    public static implicit operator MyClass(int[] args)
    {
        MyClass x = new MyClass();

        foreach (var item in args) x.values.Add(item);

        return x;
    }
}

public void Test()
{
    MyClass my = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };                        

}
```

Comment: И то верно, не подумал про неявное

Comment: Спасибо за идею, так, пожалуй, и сделаю)